# WordPress HTML Helper

Tags: php, functions, hooks, actions, html

I've played recently with WordPress Hooks and I've noticed that in order to create layouts based on the hooks the main practice is to use html in functions and combine them with logic.

I've searched for a HTML Helper (e.g. CakePHP http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) in the WordPress community but no results.
If somebody has any recommendations, plugins etc, is this a bad approach for WordPress, because I've searched the themes available free and nothing?

Comment: What is an html helper? Also note that asking for plugin recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: @Milo: here's an example from CakePHP http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Not asking for plugin recommendations, just asking if anyone has knowledge if this is implemented in WordPress and if it is or not a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there isn't one.

WordPress templating consists mostly of raw PHP and [Template Tags API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags). The API is more focused on outputting specific content, than producing specific HTML.

As result the technique is pretty much unknown in WordPress development. It doesn't mean that you can't use one, but it's just not a convention developers know/use in WordPress context.

In my personal opinion going full–blown template language in WP (Mustache, Twig, etc) is more practical than helpers, but it's probably matter of taste.